# changing button size in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, content-editor-web-part

```
<style>
.ms-formtoolbar .ms-toolbar
{
    font-size:2em
}
</style>
```

This is the code I tried in the content editor with no luck. I also tried to use pixels and no luck their either

this is a custom list form with the save button editted with javascript to say submit instead.

Here is the javascript code I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeOKButtons()
{
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
 {
  if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")
   inputs[i].value = "Submit";
 }
}

  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeOKButtons");

    </script>
```

Comment: you need to change button size or font button size ?

Comment: ideally the button size and the size of the font within.

Comment: check the answer based on your code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change button size at javascript code

```
inputs[i].style.width= "100px";

inputs[i].style.height = "100px";
```

To change Font size at javascript code

```
inputs[i].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
```

Or

```
inputs[i].style.fontSize = "10.0em";
```

So at if condition at your above code it should like

```
if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")
{   
inputs[i].value = "Submit";
//change button size
inputs[i].style.width= "100px";
inputs[i].style.height = "100px";
// change button font size 
inputs[i].style.fontSize = "10.0em";
}
```